# How to DISABLE active_admin_import action by condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, active-admin-import

How to disable active_admin_import action by condition on index page

I have a code to disable 'new, create, destroy' actions by condition.
Need to do same with active_admin_import

```
controller do
    def action_methods
      if Admin::PurchaseOrderDecorator.decorate(parent).received?
        super - %w(new create destroy)
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end

active_admin_import(
  ....
  )
```

Comment: disable like delete it or hiding it? I don't know what exactly your refering to but you can try it buy doing it on the application controller

Comment: Not to delete, hide link, route. Disable this functional in general. If parent has some condition. For example order is already 'received' I can`t upload file via active_admin_import method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `if` option

https://github.com/activeadmin-plugins/active_admin_import/commit/aa0be4bbb3151ab50911c1041415044936fba068

something like this might work

```rb
active_admin_import if: -> { Admin::PurchaseOrderDecorator.decorate(parent).received? }
```

However one more option to handle conditional access to actions through policies

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
class OrderItemPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def import?
    !order.completed?
  end
end
```

Docs

https://activeadmin.info/13-authorization-adapter.html

Pundit https://github.com/varvet/pundit